# Сохранение таблицы html

Tags: post, php, html, javascript

Написав таблицу на html подобную:

```
 <table>
     <tr>
       <td>1</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Мне требуется, чтобы пользователь мог сохранить её после изменений. Т.е не локально, а когда таблица на сервере.

На Js написан скрипт, который позволяет редактировать страницу, но мне так же требуется чтобы после изменений ячеек пользователь мог сохранить таблицу. Сам пробовал через get, но не получилось.

Мне предложили обернуть код таблицы div и js вытянуть код, а после отправить с помощью ajax обработчику. Подскажите, как написать?

Comment: Создай textarea и навесь на него wysiwyg редактор. И при сохранение будешь этот код сохранять

Comment: Ты не понял вопроса, смотри у меня есть таблица и для неё скрипты, которые позволяют её редактировать, а мне требуется возможность чтобы пользователь мог записать информацию в ячейку и сохранить!

Comment: > для неё скрипты, которые позволяют её редактировать

@qwerly, Под сохранить вы имеете в виду "сохранить изменения на сервере"? Вот эти скрипты и должны отправлять на сервер put-запрос с данными, о новой таблице.

Comment: На Js написан скрипт, который позволяет редактировать страницу, но мне так же требуется чтобы после изменений ячеек пользователь мог сохранить таблицу

Comment: На самом деле, на сервере, лучше хранить данные а не html, html же вы можете получить используя серверную и/или клиентскую шаблонизацию

Comment: Вообще почитайте о клиент серверных приложениях, по сути описанная вами задача является простейшим представителем этой категории

Answer (score 1):

Как то так:
http://jsfiddle.net/s2647/